# How to build Angular HTML template on button click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pdf-generation

I'm trying to create an HTML template to export it as a PDF File, but I'm not sure on how to do this using Angular's engine;

What I need to do basically is to build this template when I click a "Download As PDF" button, and this should take all the information I have in one component and use to create an HTML document which will be exported, but not shown on the screen or anything like that.

Since my actual screen and the format I need to have on the PDF file I'm not able to just use the same component's HTML template, so I'm looking to build the template structure I need when I click on the button.

My current component uses `mat-tabs` to display information, but in the actual PDF I need each tab to be its own individual section in the page; so I would need to build this new HTML structure **only** when I want to generate the file

Any ideas how i could do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your criteria this sounds like it needs to be a whole new component that is created specifically to the format needed for the PDF export. You'd add the correct headers such as content-disposition to have your PDF attachment.

Your next task is to determine how to get your data into that new component that is dedicated to PDF export. If you are already using a Redux/NGRX store in your app then that is probably easy enough to use.

A more common way to share data across components within the same module is to utilize an Angular service. This service is injected into both versions of the component and all important data is saved and retrieved from that service.

Comment: Sound about right, the main idea I have is that, in my current component I display information in tabs using Angular Material, but of course I can't export tabs; So I need to build a different HTML structure without the tabs, with each of them being individual sections instead; I'm not sure I understand quite well how to use a service for this scenario